# How to normalize state for nested hierarchy json in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

I am working on an app with `react`/`redux-toolkit` and I want to find the best way to normalize the state in `redux` for further manipulations.

Api Response:

```json
[
   {
      "title": "titleA",
      "id": "A",
      "type": "level1",
      "child": [
         {
            "title": "titleA1",
            "id": "A1",
            "type": "level2",
            "child": [
               {
                  "title": "titleA11",
                  "id": "A11",
                  "type": "level3"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "title": "titleB",
      "id": "B",
      "type": "level1",
      "child": [
         {
            "title": "titleB1",
            "id": "B1",
            "type": "level2",
            "child": [
               {
                  "title": "titleB11",
                  "id": "B11",
                  "type": "level3"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

We have data up to level5 in this hierarchy.

Use-case:

Initially, we get only 2 level of data and then whenever I click on level1 (titleA) it loads level3 data which should append in this hierarchy.

If we click on level1 (titleA) again, it should check child (level3) and skip the fetching part.

https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape

It have one hierarchy sample.